# ASP.NET how to log request url when exception happens?

Tags: asp.net, logging

I see thousands of "`[2012/10/31 16:08:23] FATAL: An unhandled error occurred.  - Exception : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).`" in my log file.

I think someone is attemping evil requests using an attack tool. I am not able to reproduce it on local environment.

I do this log in Global.asax, Application_Error event.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (null != ex)
    {
        Edi.Web.Logging.Logger.Fatal("An unhandled error occurred. ", ex);
    }
}
```

But how can I log the particular request url which is the dangerous "Request.Path" also?

(It's not good idea to log every request.path in Application_BeginRequest, I only want to log the one who cause this exception)

Comment: Just to add some more information, it´s unlikely that someone is "attacking" your application. This exception is thrown when some special characters are used in the querystring and your application can be passing them by allowing special chars in a search query for example. See [this](http://www.christophercrooker.com/use-any-characters-you-want-in-your-urls-with-aspnet-4-and-iis) for some more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope, This is what you want:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (null != ex)
    {
        Edi.Web.Logging.Logger.Fatal("An unhandled error occurred. " + "---Page:"
            + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), ex);
    }
}
```